# How to Configure the feature "open with pdf" in SideBarEnhancements plugin of sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

[SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) is quite a useful plugin. How do I  direct it open pdfs using the builtin pdf viewer in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the feature "open with pdf" in SideBarEnhancements plugin of sublime Text.
- Click on a file to bring up the menu.
- Select 'open with' > 'Edit Applications'
- Add the fllowing code if you are in Ubuntu

```js
            //application 3
            {
                "caption": "evince",
                "id": "side-bar-files-open-with-evince",

                "command": "side_bar_files_open_with",
                "args": {
                                    "paths": ["/usr/share/applications/evince"],
                                    "application": "evince", // linux
                                    "extensions":"pdf", //open all even folders
                                    "args":[]
                                },
                "open_automatically" : false // will close the view/tab and launch the application
            },
```

If not in 'Ubuntu' you wiill need to adjust "paths", "application", "extensions" yourself appropriately